# Virtualmin configuration error after updates

Tags: mysql, postfix, mariadb, virtualmin

I updated my VPS which I administer with Virtualmin, it runs Ubuntu 20.0.4.6

When rechecking the configuration, it stops at:

A problem was found with your Postfix virtual maps :

> The map source mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
> cannot be used : Failed to query table : You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'from where = limit 1' at
> line 1

This the problem file:

```
user = postfixuser
password = apassword
hosts = localhost
dbname = postfixadmin
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = '1'
#expansion_limit = 100
```

Can anyone see where the syntax error is?

Comment: [`goto`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/) is a keyword in ORACLE mode, I'd try to use backticks to quote it. Otherwise this looks like [mysql_table.5](https://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html) compatible.